# Terraform permissions issue when deploying from GCP gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to deploy some GCP resources using terraform.

1. Executed gcloud auth login (authenticated with my gcp
   account, assigned gcp project).
2. Executed gcloud auth application-default login.
3. Assigned roles to my useraccount (user99@gmail.com) at project level and the Terraform Service Account at organisation level.

Now, when I run terraform scripts from my CLI on my local machine, I get the "Error 403: The caller does not have permissions" error.

My question is:

1. When running terraform commands from my local machines CLI, which account is terraform using to deploy resources (user99@gmail.com or Terraform Service Account)?
2. Is Terraform complaining about missing permissions for my user99@gmail.com or the Terraform Service Account?
3. Is there a way to check which account is being used to deploy resources on GCP?
4. Without changing the project on gcloud auth login, can we deploy resources in other GCP projects?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on a (e.g. local) host (i.e. that's not on GCP):

1. with `gcloud` and you've `gcloud auth application-default-login` then (!) Terraform should be using that user's credentials (`gcloud config get-value account`).
2. and the environment exports `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (and this correctly points to a service account's key), then the Service Account will be used.

If you're running Terraform on GCP (e.g. on Compute Engine) then the Compute Engine's service account will be automatically determined by ADCs (see below).

Google Provider Configuration [Authentication](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#authentication)

Application Default Credentials (ADCs) [Finding Credentials Automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically)

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin for your response and the links.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check which account is being used to deploy resources on GCP?

This simple code will show you which account is used to terraform resources:

```
data "google_client_openid_userinfo" "me" {
}

output "my-email" {
  value = data.google_client_openid_userinfo.me.email
}
```

> Without changing the project on gcloud auth login, can we deploy resources in other GCP projects?

Actually, you can rely on self_links that contain full path with the project itself, so you can specify different projects. However, the proper way would be to use different provider aliases for each of the project.

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations